# ISC-DHCPD & BIND9: Dynamic DNS interaction

Tags: bind, unix, isc-dhcp

I am running `isc-dhcpd-4.4.1` and `BIND 9.11.6` daemons on FreeBSD 11.2 server for a small company.

`dhcpd` serves a number of Windows stations (assigning them mostly static IP addresses), several special-purpose devices (getting static public IP addresses - must be available to our clients) and also different portable devices connecting the network through WiFi (which get addresses from a predefined range `192.168.120.50 - 192.168.120.200`). The dynamically assigned clients get registered by the BIND `named` and their names are available both for forward and reverse DNS resolution. As the lease time for portable devices is short, they are automatically removed from DNS whenever they cease communicating.

So far, this arrangement works perfectly.

Now my question:

Is it possible to force DNS registration/removal for some specific portable devices that are expected to get always the same (statically defined) address? If so, how to configure it?

Comment: I would really make this two different questions. Can you remove the second question, and copy your introduction text plus the second question to a new question? PS: Welcome to ServerFault!

Comment: @Tommiie - Thanks for your advice.